Citect SCADA - Updating project from Panasonic PLC to Allen Bradley PLC?
I have a Citect SCADA 2018 project that was previously interfacing with a Panasonic PLC (programmed in FPwin Pro 6). We have since changed our PLCs over to Allen Bradley CompactLogix controllers (running Studio 5000 v36). In the process of translating the code between the two software, tag names have changed for push-buttons and value readouts.
How would I go about changing which tags from the AB PLC the Citect software looks at for various push-buttons and data readouts? I was not the person who originally made the Citect project nor the original creator of the AB program. Additionally, the PLC is currently not online or connected to the computer running Citect at this moment.
I have attempted to open Citect Explorer (an application I see in a lot of how-to videos), but the software I'm running does not have that application at this time. Therefore, I don't know if there's a way (preferably fairly easy) to import tag data for push-buttons and values.
I currently have my tag data from my Studio 5000 project exported as a .csv file.
